# Reverse Geolocator returns address as 'Antarctica'

Tags: geolocation, xamarin.forms, arcgis, esri

Attempting to use GetAddressesForPositionAsync() in order to find the list of possible addresses that my coordinates can point too. I call the map using esri ArcGIS mapping and add it to a mapview

```
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Map myMap = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Map(SpatialReference.Create(4326));
myMapView = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms.MapView();
geoCoder = new Geocoder();
//assign the map to a mapview
myMapView.Map = myMap;
```

then use an event handler to wait for the user to double tap the screen.

```
 //event handler
 myMapView.GeoViewDoubleTapped += new EventHandler<Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms.GeoViewInputEventArgs>(geotappedMap);

 //the location for the pin and sent to geothings()
 double Lat = ((((Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms.GeoViewInputEventArgs)e).Location.X));
 double Lng = ((((Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms.GeoViewInputEventArgs)e).Location.Y));
 myLocation = new MapPoint(Lat, Lng);
```

The program places a marker there and then uses the coordinates of where the tap was to call get position.

```
 public async void geothings(Object sender, EventArgs e, Position p)
    {
        try
        {
        var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(p);

        foreach (var address in possibleAddresses)
            _label2.Text += "\n\n" + address;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error Getting Address", ex.Message, "Close");
        }
    }
```

the function runs without a problem except the label is updated with the value 'Antarctica' after being called. Does anyone know why or how this is happening?

Comment: can you add the Lat & Lng values that is being pass to MapPoint. Also, updating the SpatialReference to the point helps to get better results.